# Listing users who have posts with Ruby on Rails 5

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Currently I have this query to pull all users who have an avatar:

```
@users = User.all.order('RANDOM()').where.not(avatar: nil)
```

However I also need to check the users who have posts. How can I do that since the posts are in a different table?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use the association between User and Post (if Post is your model), this will check whether the foreign key and primary key in both cases match, what eventually checks if a User has recorded some Post:

```
User.order('RANDOM()').joins(:posts).where.not(avatar: nil)
# SELECT "users".*
# FROM "users"
# INNER JOIN "posts" ON
# "posts"."user_id" = "users"."id"
# WHERE ("users"."avatar" IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY RANDOM()
```

In other way you could check if the id of the associated model (the one that depends in User) is not nil, that means, it exists as an associated record, like:

```
User.order('RANDOM()').joins(:posts).where.not(avatar: nil)
                                    .where.not(posts: { id: nil })
```

Comment: To avoid fetching duplicate user records, you could add a `GROUP BY` clause to the query: `group('users.id')`.

Comment: I love how simple and elegant this solution, however it doesnt really filter. It still shows all users including the ones doesnt have post 

Comment: Ah, it can be about my is_approved boolean field for posts. this works User.order('RANDOM()').where.not(avatar: nil).joins(:posts).where(posts: {is_approved: true})

Comment: In fact, if a user doesn't have a reference to a post, then `INNER JOIN "posts" ON "posts"."user_id" = "users"."id"` wouldn't add it to the query result. You could also try a combination of distinct and where to check both attributes `User.distinct.joins(:posts).where.not(avatar: nil, posts: { id: nil })`.

Comment: @w_hile thanks for the suggestion mate! That helped a lot!

Comment: I think for readability your query could be something like `User.joins(:posts).where.not(avatar: nil, posts: { is_approved: false }).order('RANDOM()')`, just a recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

One way to get users with both an avatar and posts is to use SQL's `EXISTS` operator. We can then leverage ActiveRecord's scopes to make these queries reusable:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  scope :with_avatar, -> { where.not(avatar: nil) }
  scope :with_posts, -> { where('EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM posts WHERE user_id = users.id)') }
end
```

Now in your controller you can do:

```
@users = User.order('RANDOM()').with_avatar.with_posts
```

Hope this helps!